# Anyone know the script to this HTML mobile grid homepage?

Tags: html, mobile

Mostly the image shows it all. But I would like to know if anyone has the script to this code, or something similar to it where I could easily change it to look like this. 
Thanks. 
( view image at; https://ibb.co/cnHqgb (can’t upload one to here))

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use the Developer console on your web browser, if you are referring to javascript; Javascript is a client side scripting technology which means it is run on the clients computer. All resources for the web page rendering are available on the "client computer". Visit here for information on what client side means: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjqhfWyubLYAhUQ4mMKHfOaAbEQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FClient-side&usg=AOvVaw2_tROJ3t6y_go_JvYx5Cbc
PHP on the other hand is also a scripting technology but is run on the server, but PHP only serves what scripting your browser recognizes which is html, javascript, java, flash etc...
Open the developers console and look under the resources tab and you should have a listing of all the resources for the page under question. You can then download them and look at the source code that is used for browser rendering. You must keep in mind that sites are intellectual property and usually contain copyright footers which means while you can research and learn different design layouts for websites by inspecting source code, if you steal a site owners exact intellectual property for displaying a website you could be held legally responsible.